# how to convert values of type float and double into binary format and push into vector of type uint8_t?

Tags: c++, vector, serialization, floating-point

I want to know  how to convert values of float and double into binary format and push into vector of type uint8_t

```
Eg : float x  = 23.22;
     double z = 2.32232;
```

and store them into vector while serializing

> vector<uint8_t> data.

and also convert back into original value  while deserializing.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "binary format". Floats and doubles are stored in memory as bits so they are binary. Though that binary format may be not compatible with different machine if you want to send them over the network. Please clarify.

Comment: @Slava, yes I want to convert them into bytes ... I have other types  like int32 and int64 which I convert  into bytes of array for eg int32 a = 12 then this get convert into {11 23 34 0} for serializing ( LEB128 encoded)  there value are between  0 to 255 ... I want to do same for float and double..

Comment: See [bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). You can also use `memcpy` directly.

Comment: They are handled in a binary format. Not in a binary integer format. You can serialize them as is to a file. To serialize them to a byte stream, I believe the official approved approach is to memcpy to a byte array of the proper size. The binary format is not necessarily the same between platforms, but is more commonly so then it used to be. I'd double check that the 2 ends use the same binary format.

Comment: You can simply do `memcpy( pointer_to_uint8t, &float_var, sizeof(float) )` and vice versa, but again this is not portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to push them into vector and pop them (like a stack) you can do this:

```
void push( std::vector<uint8_t> &v, float f )
{
   auto offs = v.size();
   v.resize( offs + sizeof( f ) );
   std::memcpy( v.data() + offs, &f, sizeof( f ) );
}

float popFloat( std::vector<uint8_t> &v )
{
    float f = 0;
    if( v.size() >= sizeof( f ) ) {
        auto offs = v.size() - sizeof( f );
        std::memcpy( &f, v.data() + offs, sizeof( f ) );
        v.resize( offs );
    }
    return f;
}
```

Note this would store them in not portable format, but should work for storing/reading them to/from file on the same hardware.

You may rewrite those 2 functions as template and it will work with all integral and floating point types ( `short` `int` `long` `double` etc )

Comment: Thank for the answer, If this is not something portable..which is the portable prefered format that is used?

Comment: Portable format without using libraries is string. Portable binary format will require a library that would take care of proper representation.